# jQuery and Cross Domain POST Requests

Tags: jquery, http-post, cross-domain-policy

I'm developing a jQuery plug-in that will be a connector for some REST API.
The implementation is straight forward, but the same origin policy is definitely painfull.
I need to perform mostly POST requests.

I also tried to implement the OPTIONS method and returning (is python, but the meaning should be clear)

```
def options(self):
  self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = self.request.host_url
  self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
  self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'x-requested-with'
  self.response.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
```

still doesn't work... any idea ?

PS: I have seen that there are other question with a similar topic but i need a specific solution for POST method (GET could be easely implemented by using iframes)

Javascript example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: options.protocol+'://'+options.host+':'+options.port+'/'+method,
    data: rawData,
    async:false,
    dataType: "json",
    type:"POST",
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert('asd');
        result.data = data;
        alert(data);
    },
    error:function(lol){
        alert('omggg !!!!'+lol);
    }

});
```

EDIT: added javascript code example

Comment: Are the cross domain headers supported in the browsers that you need to support?

Comment: Did you try only with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and setting it to `*`? That have always worked for me.

Comment: well, I just found an article that was explaining the role of those headers. For the test i was using firefox and acutally i got the return body (thx httpfox) but I can't get the success method called (jQuery.ajax)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit of a fiddle sometimes, some thoughts:

- CORS is only supported by fairly modern browsers, so you'll need to be sure you're using one of those.
- IE only supports CORS via the [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, not the standard `XMLHttpRequest` object, but jQuery doesn't specifically cater for that (yet; I have to admit I'm slightly surprised and <s>expect it will before too long</s>), so you have to add special handling to make this work on IE (and then only IE8 and above). **Edit**: Shockingly, apparently the jQuery team have had that request and *denied* it: [ticket #8283](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283) That makes ***no*** sense.
- Are you sure about that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value? It *looks* like it's only allowing access from the server it's on. That header is meant to specify what origins the server will allow the request to *come* from. (And `*` is allowed, to mean "anywhere.")
- I seem to recall from my experiments with Firefox on this that it was finicky about my allowing methods when responding to the `OPTIONS` request that it hadn't asked for.
- Double-check that you're allowing **all** of the headers that the request is sending; in your example it looks like you're only allowing one header (`x-requested-with`), but I bet there will be others in the actual request.

FWIW (I'm not a Python guy), here's my JSP code that works, perhaps it will be useful — I think the object names are clear enough to be readable even if you don't do Java (and who knows, maybe you do):

```
String corsOrigin, corsMethod, corsHeaders;

// Find out what the request is asking for
corsOrigin = request.getHeader("Origin");
corsMethod = request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method");
corsHeaders = request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
if (corsOrigin == null || corsOrigin.equals("null")) {
    // Requests from a `file://` path seem to come through without an
    // origin or with "null" (literally) as the origin.
    // In my case, for testing, I wanted to allow those and so I output
    // "*", but you may want to go another way.
    corsOrigin = "*";
}

// Add headers allowing specifically what was requested
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", corsOrigin);
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", corsMethod);
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", corsHeaders);
if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS"))
{
    // Done, no body in response to OPTIONS
    return;
}
// Processing the GET or POST here; output the body of the response
```

Note that I'm using exactly the same logic for `GET`, `POST`, and `OPTIONS` except that in the case of OPTIONS, I don't output a response body.