# Perform GET request using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to perform the following GET request,

```
telnet somesite.com 80
GET /index.html HTTP/1.0
```

using javascript, jQuery.

I've tried to follow the instructions in [this site](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/the-perfect-jquery-ajax-request/) in particular the following code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://somesite.com',
  success:function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

but It doesn't work!

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Which http error do you get?

Comment: You cannot do cross-domain ajax query. see [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code itself, so it does suggest that you're trying to access a page on a different domain, as suggested by @psal above.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",  
         url: "http://somesite.com",
     timeout: 300000,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: success,
       error: failure
});

function failure(response) {
    alert(response);
}
function success(response) {
    alert(response);
}
```

Comment: It returns [object Object]

Comment: Seems like there is some issue with URL , is there any method you want to access from this URL?

Answer (score 1):

by your code im assuming you are doing a cross domain ajax request. Which are automatically blocked by the browser.

you can either use the allow domain header using Cors see this [Cross Domain Get Request in JS/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199640/cross-domain-get-request-in-js-jquery)

or switch to JSONP

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform a cross domain request try this

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/2E8Gq/1/)

You can use this in your head tag

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/IonicaBizau/jQuery-cross-domain-requests/master/js/jquery.xdomainajax.js">
</script>
```

### code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://somsite.com', // Or your web page link
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
      alert(res);
    }
  });
```