# GWT Server to server communication

Tags: gwt

I have 2 different gwt applications, both on different machines, but they need to communicate.
Is their a simple way, using the gwt mechanisem to do it and access an existing servlet on another gwt application, or do i need to open another http connection between them some other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross Domain Get Request in JS/JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199640/cross-domain-get-request-in-js-jquery)

Comment: The easiest solution is to have your servers talk to each other. Making clients communicate across domains is more complex, but the question I linked to provides some options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most standardized way to do that is to use [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html): it is future prone and a lot of work was already done for you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions

Your issue cannot be considered as a GWT problem since GWT is limited to java script, and you need real java methods to communicate together, doing it through GWT is at best unperformant and at worse the source of many problems (since you are not inside a browser, and using a "virtual browser" to execute your javascript might lead to subtile very hard to understand differences)